# how do i replicate spree delete behavior?

Tags: ruby, spree

I wish to replicate the delete behavior, i manage to delete the data from the database with

```
    def destroy
        @my_object = Spree::MyObject.find(params[:id])
        @my_object.destroy

        flash[:success] = Spree.t('notice_messages.object_deleted')

        respond_with(@my_object) do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to collection_url }
            format.js { render :partial => 'destroy' }
        end
    end
```

and a helper

```
<%= link_to_delete my_object, :url => "#{main_app.admin_objectarea_obejects_url}/#{ad_zone.id}", :no_text => true %>
```

but it doesn't fire the jquery behavior, the funny thing is if a change the url, for something like `"http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/products/apache-baseball-jersey"`, the behavior work and the row is removed

Answer (score 0):

I find out that the logic was right, it was returning a falior because of a missing translation, that jquery somehow translate in error